# Extend blade engine in Laravel to use different views directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a Laravel project and I am very new to it. For now, I want to use blade templates to render views but I want it to search for views in different directories like `<custom_dir>\views` instead of default `resources/views`.
The `<custom_dir>` will be dynamic (it can be a variable).

Any ideas? I was thinking of a custom service provider and then extend the default  function which renders views in Laravel inside it. But not sure how to implement it.

**Edit:**
I have user this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-blade) to extend the default functionality of include function in blade template engine. But this overrides the include functionality. I want to change the path and then call the default blade functionality

Comment: Technically speaking this is not a blade issue, blade only comes into play after you've resolved the view to a file. Also you should try to find an alternative solution to your problem rather than doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why do you want to put views somewhere else? What's the benefit?

Comment: I am developing a modular application and every module will have the respective views inside the particular folders

Comment: Basically I want the blade engine to look for views inside the particular module's view directory first and if not found, then it will search in resources/views. The same way it happens in Codeigniter's modular architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably append the path to the configuration:

1) Statically, by modifying file `config/view.php`

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('resources/views')),
    //more paths here
],
```

2) Dynamically at runtime:

```
$paths = config('view.paths');
$paths[] = $newPathToAdd;
config(["view.paths" => $paths ]);
```

I suggest you use this in moderation otherwise you will just end up with a mess of directories with no real specified purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom directories in `resources\views` directory and use them with something like this:

```
return view($customDirectory.'.index');
```

Where `index` is a template inside custom directory.

Comment: I want it to search for directories outside of the resources folder. Is it possible to extend the function which renders views in Laravel inside a service provider?